# Invoke a java Vector from JSP to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, vector

I have this object inside a body of my JSP pages.

```
'<%
    String stato = (String) session.getAttribute("stato");
    Utente u = (Utente) session.getAttribute("utente");
    UtenteDAO uDAO = new UtenteDAO();
    PagamentoDAO pDAO = new PagamentoDAO();
    ProdottoDAO prDAO = new ProdottoDAO();
    OrdiniDAO oDAO = new OrdiniDAO();
    DatiFisiciDAO dfDAO = new DatiFisiciDAO();
    int numClienti = uDAO.ContaClienti();
    Vector<Utente> utenti = uDAO.getAllClienti();
    Vector<Pagamento> pagamenti = pDAO.getAll();
    Vector<Prodotto> magliette = prDAO.getMagliette();
    Vector<Prodotto> barrette = prDAO.getBarrette();
    Vector<Prodotto> integratori = prDAO.getIntegratori();
    Vector<Ordini> ordini = oDAO.getAll();
    Vector<DatiFisici> dati = dfDAO.getAll();
    %>'
```

I want to invoke the java vector called "utenti" in a Javascript function. Is it possible to realize that?

Comment: No. The Java code is executed at the server side to produce HTML containing JavaScript code. At the time the browser at the client side (usually running on a different computer) has received this HTML and starts to execute the JavaScript code the Java objects are history (and they existed at a different location far away). Use the browser's "Show Sourcecode" command to see the HTML code created by the JSP at server side. You have to use something like AJAX or Websockets to let the browser communicate with the server.

Comment: There are two different execution contexts here. Java/JSP at server side and JavaScript at client side. The only relation between them is that the first one generates the code for the second one.

Comment: but could i call the dao object directly inside the javascript function?  This way by calling the object in the function I could call all of its methods

Comment: Um, no. Please try to understand what these two execution contexts really mean. The Java context is on the server. Its purpose is create a HTML response out of a HTTP request. JSP is not more than a text templating machine. During execution there exists some Java objects like the DAO object and the output is the HTML text. The included JavaScript code here is only another kind of text, not more. After that all local objects are garbage collected and aren't further accessable. Then the web server sends the resulting HTML to the client. Then the browser parses the HTML and executes the JS code.

Comment: At this point in time the Java objects on the server side are long gone. And even they would exist, they are on the server side. Inside a totally separated process usually running on a different machine. There is no way the browser can access them. The browser doesn't know wether the HTML text was created by a Java process or a different language. For the browser the server is a black box. You can only define an API (like REST, SOAP or Websocket) over HTTP which the client (browser) can call.

Comment: Yes, now I have undertand. Thank you so much for your support.